# Flutter upgrade cocapods version

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, homebrew

I'm trying to update my cocoapods version used by flutter. I already upgraded cocoapods by running `sudo gem install cocoapods`.
When I run `pod --version` anywhere in the terminal it returns version `1.10.1` but when I run it inside my flutter ios project (path myProject/ios) it returns version `1.9.3` and also flutter doctor tells me that cocoapods is using version `1.9.3`.

I also tried running `brew update` and `brew upgrade cocoapods` as well as `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`.

Can anybody tell me how to align the version used inside my flutter project with the globally (?) installed cocoapods version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all of the commands in the question I also ran `sudo gem update --system` in my projects\ios folder which finally solved the problem.